# /etc/hosts will not update/refresh at all

Tags: macos, dns, hosts

I add to my `/etc/hosts` file this :

```
127.0.0.1 youtube.com
```

Save the file. Flush everything with :

```
dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Reboot my computer 30 times.

Then I run:

```
dscacheutil -q host -a name youtube.com
```

And I get :

```
name: youtube.com
ip_address: 216.58.220.46
```

Clear my cache completely since the beginning of time in any browser, go to : `youtube.com`, and I get `youtube.com`, not my localhost.

I'm using OS X 10.10.5, Yosemite.

Comment: Is `/etc/hosts` still in use on OS X 10.10?

Comment: @CousinCocaine It appears so, but and it seems like it works for other folks. Though I've read a handful of threads where folks seem to be having similar issues.

Comment: I thought 10.10 moved away from /etc/hosts. Dont know the new way/mechanism of doing this. Not sure though.

Comment: First, dscacheutil and mDNSResponder doesn't affect /etc/hosts.  Secondly, watch out with https sites as they don't play nice with these tricks.  Additionally sites as facebook and youtube have a huge load of other hostnames.  Blocking them using /etc/hosts is next to impossible.  Better use something like Little Snitch if you really need to block those.

Comment: The problem stands around the 30 times.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check your hosts file, because probably it's malformed. It should look similar to this one:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       youtube.com
127.0.0.1       www.youtube.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Opening the file with `sudo nano /etc/hosts` it should have a trailing empty line. All entries for 127.0.0.1 should be added above the broadcasthost. The space between IP-address and hostname should be one tab: <kbd>⇥</kbd>.

After writing the file to disk with nano, the changes should take effect immediately (usually without executing any dnscacheutil or killall commands). Check this with `ping youtube.com`.

Google Chrome is (probably) the only app which doesn't adhere properly (as a test in a VM revealed).

Comment: OOC, can I use the hosts file to make youtube.com alias to a different remote site? For example, going to youtube.com would be google.com ?

Comment: @Trip Sure! That was the purpose of the hosts file in ancient days: <ip-address-google.com> tab youtube.com and www.youtube.com but only if the google-ip is different than the youtube-ip. In my case it isn't: both redirect to 216.58.213.46

Comment: Ah so it can only be redirected to a specific IP then and not a general address ( ie. bobmarley.com )?

Comment: @Trip On the left side has to be an ip-address and on the right a hostname.

Comment: Ah thanks so much good sir. You helped me so much. There's no trendy way to mask **just** a subdomain is there?

Comment: @Trip I don't really understand your question. What do you want to achieve? Maybe you should ask a second question here.

Comment: True. Only if you're interested! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847606/can-i-alias-a-localhost-subdomain-to-a-remote-s3-host Thanks again so much!!

Comment: From personnal use and `man hosts`:
• There is not any rule requiring any empty line at th end of `/etc/hosts` file.
• There is no mandatory order between entries.
• The separator is any number of blanks or tab characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

No reboot required.

"It works!" for me, OS X 10.11.6

Answer (score 1):

If the site has both IPV4 and IPV6 DNS (you can see this by entering the following in terminal, e.g. where google.com is the domain you are trying to block):

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name google.com
```

If the result looks like this:

```
name: google.com
ipv6_address: 2a00:1450:400f:80c::200e

name: google.com
ip_address: 172.217.21.142
```

Then you will need to add a line in the hosts file to also block the IPV6 address.

The following worked for me.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 google.com
::  google.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

Afterwards, checking it in terminal again:

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name google.com
name: google.com
ipv6_address: ::

name: google.com
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score -2):

100% working try so:

```
Ex:
0.0.0.0 example.com
::  example.com
0.0.0.0 www.example.com
::  www.example.com
```

You have to put 0.0.0.0 and :: both for www. or without www

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. Please have a look at the [faq] to see what needs to be considered in writing good answers. Right now it‘s not really clear how your answer actually helps to solve the problem described in the question. To amend your answer just use the „edit“ link at the bottom of your text.