# Not able to access localhost via local IP

Tags: macos, network, wifi, osx-server

I want to connect to my local Web Server (NodeJS server) which runs on my MacBook with my iPhone.

On my Mac I can access the server via `http://localhost:3000/`.
Now all it should take is to replace localhost with my Mac's local IP address like this `http://192.168.0.13:3000/`. However, on my iPhone I cannot access the server this way and even when I try to open `http://192.168.0.13:3000/` on my Mac there is no connection being established.

This is definitely a problem with my Mac and not with my program because when I run the server on Windows and try to connect to it with the local IP address it works just fine.

Also trying this in another Wi-Fi Network does not help or changing the port does not change anything either.

I am using Mac OSX 10.11.5 and my firewall is turned off.

How can I solve this problem?

Routing Tables (`netstat -r`)

(Deleted)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44273/discussion-on-question-by-hansmu158-not-able-to-access-localhost-via-local-ip).

Comment: I was tempted to vote to close as too broad, but from all the comments - let's see if an overview of how to determine if the OP thinking it's really on the Mac is in fact the cause.

Comment: Hi HansMu158, did you ever figure out why browsing to your server's IP address didn't work? I may have a similar problem as yours and wonder if you have suggestions. Thanks! See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/284762/53510

Comment: @Ryan Yeah, I figured out that the problem was caused by an old anti virus program (Eset) I had on my Mac which, although it was neither active nor running, had a firewall which blocked almost all incoming traffic. I had a brief look at your problem… When you are developing with a local server it is necessary to set the hostname of the server to "0.0.0.0" to allow access from your network. Maybe your developing environment is not doing that by itself, so you could have a look into that.

Comment: I found that none of the answers below worked using the Safari browser, but when I changed to Chrome, I could view the server at myname.local:3000, where ```myname``` is the name of the machine running the server.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell the behavior is correct. A basic node web server uses dns.js to resolve any hostname – which itself uses the system's DNS resolution method.

A hostname "127.0.0.1" as well as "localhost" can't be resolved by OS X's mDNS responder (neither non-reverse nor reverse).

So either use your Mac's IP (i.e. 192.168.0.13) or its hostname (e.g. tims-macbook-pro) as hostname. To advertise the service in Bonjour you have to use *dns-sd*.

Or create several listening IPs like in [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033178/how-to-use-nodejs-listen-multiple-ips).

Comment: That may be correct, but it also does not work with a MAMP Apache Server. Also the same configuration works on Windows which is something I do not quite understand.

Comment: @HansMu158 Please ask a second question regarding your MAMP config & node. If possible include some relevant parts of the config files (e.g. apache), a somehow stripped *.js file containing the `http.createServer(handler).listen` part and the MAMP config details.

Comment: I really think this problem is not specific to MAMP and my Node JS server. Firstly, the Node Server can be run and accessed via local IP on windows. Furthermore even ssh-ing into my MacBook (which is enabled under sharing) does only work with local host, not with local IP. So `ssh Tim@localhost` works just fine, whereas `ssh Tim@192.168.0.13` gives me the following error: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: Is there any way for me to see which connection are incoming on the Mac and which are let through or blocked?

Comment: And as response for the ssh problem: I do not use non-OSX ssh solutions and `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow` do not exist. After deleting the whole `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, ssh still not works and gives me the same error. The file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` does not exit either.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to check if the remote host is able to access the Mac and therefore monitoring incoming connection would be helpful, I figured.

Comment: @HansMu158 I recommend to use nc (netcat) and nmap on your Mac **and** on a remote host. nc may create an arbitrary open port and nmap checks this. lsof is also helpful. And not to forget Wireshark!!

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will try that and see what the result is.

Comment: So after some experimenting I still did not get it to work. All I found out is that my server is not seen when running `sudo netstat -a`. Does this have something to say?

Comment: @HansMu158 I would first choose `nmap 127.0.0.1` and `nmap 192.168.0.13`. Then choose `sudo lsof | grep LISTEN` and/or `sudo netstat -a | grep LISTEN`. Which "server" do you mention in your comment? node-http, apache-http/https?

Comment: I am talking about both servers right now. `nmap 192.168.0.13` gives me the following result: `PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
3000/tcp open  ppp
8888/tcp open  sun-answerbook` Port 3000 and 8888 are for my servers but I strangely cannot access some via the local IP

Comment: @HansMu158 Did you check your hosts file already? Do you have any custom routes enabled? Did you set up and use some VPN connections/providers?

Comment: For what should I check my hosts file? And I am not exactly sure about VPN, I enabled TOR once, I think.

Comment: @HansMu158 The default hosts file looks like [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208250/93229) (without the youtube lines of course). You may add your routing table to your question: `netstat -r`. IPv6 is not needed here.

Comment: Okay, I have attached both of them above in my original question.

Comment: Does this help to find out what the problem is?

Comment: No errors visible. I would disable awdl0 temporarily though: `sudo ifconfig awdl0 down`. Probably I'd need to have access to the system to solve the problem...

Comment: Why would you disable it? And what would you do if you had access?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44534/discussion-between-hansmu158-and-klanomath).

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue in three ways:

1. Run a port scanning tool from the iPhone to make sure the port is actually open on the Mac. Firewall rules, improper NAT, router / switch issues all can be the cause of another device not getting the correct route to your Mac. If the PC can port scan or browse the Mac web server, you'll know it's not necessarily the Mac.
2. DNS issues - instead of hard coding the IP address, you could navigate to http://192.168.0.13.xip.io - that will make sure the web browser works if the iOS device is on an IPv6 only configuration. Unlikely, but at some point this will be more common. You could also use the Mac's IPv6 address instead of the IPv4 address.
3. Proxy setup on iOS - again, if your iOS device has a VPN or web proxy configured, it won't necessarily get to the Mac web server. The steps to triage that are also varied.

Comment: 1. The iPhone Port Scanning Tool shows the port is open. Also a Port Scan on Mac finds the port.

Comment: 2. Switching to this URL sadly does not work and 3. I do not have a proxy set up on my iOS device

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your local ip address into httpd.conf (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf) as below:

```
Listen 12.34.56.78:80
```

Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
ports, instead of the default.

Save, close and restart apache with `sudo apachectl restart`.